# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tournaments"} but rake routes shows tournaments#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tournaments"}

```
class TournamentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @tournament = Tournament.new
  end

  def create
    @tournament = Tournament.new(params[:tournament].permit(:description))
    if @tournament.save
      #flash[:notice] = 'tournament was successfully created.'
      #set up links


      redirect_to :action => 'show'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @tournament = Tournament.first
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :tournaments do 
    member do
      get "results"
    end

    resources :opportunities do
      member do
        get 'rate'
      end
    end
  end
```

Performing rake routes displays:

...

```
tournament GET    /tournaments/:id(.:format)       tournaments#show
```

...

What am I doing wrong? (will update as I progress through this noob issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide an ID, of the tournament instance you wish to show. It's right there as `:id` in the `rake routes` output.

If the error is occurring when you execute your `create` action, you may want to `redirect_to tournament_path(@tournament)` (or just `redirect_to @tournament`).